# when the socket invalid

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I have Tcp server. I use linux c api `socket(`), `bind()`, `listen()`, `select()`, `accept()`  to wait the client to connect.

when I pull and plug the network cable, the select have no error return and it can normally wait the client connect and so on.

when I change my ip address use

```
 ifconfig eth0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xx netmask 255.255.255.0
```

(in same segment), the select have no error return and then client use this new ip to connect my server, it is alse success

When I should restart my server?

ps: `bind()` is use `INADDR_ANY`

Comment: According to your own observations, never.

Comment: What is your expecation?

Comment: @Nilesh I want to know when the socket fd is invalid, then I should restart server. But now I don't know when the socket fd is invalid, test some situation, I found the socket fd is always valid. I can't confirm the socket fd is always valid

Comment: A listening socket FD only becomes invalid when you close it. Surely you know when you've done that?

Comment: In other words, pulling out the cable has no effect on the *listening* socket, only on *connected* sockets.  You do not need to restart the listening socket unless you bound it to a specific interface's IP and that interface IP changes. In that case, you need to monitor the interface you bound to, the socket will not do that for you.

Comment: @EJP no, I am not close socket fd. I just consider the external effect, such as network interface down/up, ip address change and so on

Comment: In that case you're asking a different question. You're not asking about the *socket FD*, you're asking about the *socket*. However the answer is still the same. The socket remains valid until closed. As long as it is bound to `INADDR_ANY,` anybody can connect to it. If however you bind it to a specific IP address and that IP address disappears, nobody will be able to connect to the socket: however the socket itself is still valid and won't report any error conditions that would lead you to conclude otherwise. Solution: don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The listening socket remains valid until closed. As long as it is bound to `INADDR_ANY,` anybody can connect to it.

If however you bind it to a specific IP address and that IP address disappears, nobody will be able to connect to the socket: however the socket itself is still valid and won't report any error conditions that would lead you to conclude otherwise. Solution: don't.

Comment: Ths, this answer is what i want to know, Thank you